# Why does SQLCMD mode seem to execute xp_cmdshell out of sequence when connecting to other servers?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, xp-cmdshell

If I connect to server "ServerA.domain.com" and execute the following in SQLCMD mode of SQL Management Studio:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'
:CONNECT ServerB.domain.com
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'
```

Then the output is:

```
Connecting to ServerB.domain.com...
output
---------------------------------------
ServerB
NULL

(2 rows affected)

output
------------------------------------------
ServerB
NULL

(2 rows affected)

Disconnecting connection from ServerB.domain.com...
```

It appears to execute the :CONNECT command prior to the first xp_cmdshell command, despite the sequence of the script.  What is the reason for this, and can it be prevented?

Comment: The two `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'` are in the same batch. Do you get expected behavior if you insert a `GO` batch separator line before your `:CONNECT` line?

Comment: Adding a batch separator does give the result I am looking for.  Even though it does not (in my opinion) answer the question of why SQL seems to execute the statements out of order, it does solve the problem I was having.  So, if you would like to post that as an answer I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious from the [`sqlcmd` Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility#sqlcmd-commands) documentation, but it does provide the hint:

> Commands are executed immediately. They are not put in the execution buffer as Transact-SQL statements are.

The implication here is that with the following .sql file:

```sql
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'
:CONNECT ServerB.domain.com
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'
```

The `:CONNECT ServerB.domain.com` gets executed first followed by the two buffered statements `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'`, which correlates with the behavior you are seeing.

To get the expected behavior you need to add a `GO` batch separator:

```sql
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'
GO
:CONNECT ServerB.domain.com
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'hostname'
```